# Angular 2+, specify input type attribute inside a ngFor created form

Tags: forms, angular, ngfor

UPDATE-----

I can show a datepicker with a method, passing "date" to input type. But Now I want to use a nicer component, i.e. Angular Material Datepicker.

now my code is the following; I can't see datepicker label and I followed the component guide to use it... but I have only an empty field...

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let meta of state.metaById; let i = index" style="margin: 5px">
      <label>{{meta.nome}}</label>
      <mat-form-field *ngIf="indovinaTipo(meta.nome)=='date'">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Seleziona una data">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" #nome (input)="inputInArray(nome.value, i)">
    </div>
    <button>...<button>
</form>
```

ORIGINAL POST ---

I have a dinamic generated form, thanks to an *ngFor. It works, but I need to specify different input types for some iterations of the for.

Is it possible ?

Here is the code

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let meta of state.metaById; let i = index" style="margin: 5px">
      <label>{{meta.nome}}</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" #nome (input)="inputInArray(nome.value, i)">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="doClick()">invia
    </button>
  </form>
```

Comment: can't you specify it in your data and then can assign to [type] property of input, or you can always create a method to return that correct type according to the meta

Comment: seems right, I'm trying this

Comment: Ok, it seems to work, the problem is a "date" input field is not supported by every browser. Is there a way I can use a custom datepicker component in that case ?

Comment: sure, why not you can put a ngIf before your input and if it has to be date render a custom datepicker instead of an input box

Comment: oh dear, a feel a bit Idiot :) I'll try. Thanks

Comment: it's more difficult than I tought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you function **indovinaTipo(meta.nome)** is returning the correct value of date when you want to render datepicker, I have tried the following code in plunker and it works just fine, I'm not sure about your data structure, just putting mock values for test

```
state = [
      {nome: 'a'}
      {nome: 'date'}
      ]



<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let meta of state; let i = index" style="margin: 5px">
      <label>{{meta.nome}}</label>

      <mat-form-field *ngIf="meta.nome==='date'">
       <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>

   <input *ngIf="meta.nome!='date'" type="text" class="form-control" #nome (input)="inputInArray(nome.value, i)">
    </div>
</form>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VCfo7zsX9VRuM9jrR531?p=preview)

Comment: can you please post plunker url ?

Comment: Ok, I was missing a component import, but strangely the IDE didn't tell me about it. It was MatNativeDateModule, in addition to MatDatepickerModule